# Ethernet port works randomly on startup, restart always fixes issue

Tags: networking, windows-10, internet, ethernet

I have a custom PC that I built awhile ago that has a Asus rampage motherboard, don't have the exact model number off the top of my head. I have it wired with ethernet rather than wireless and the past few months every say 1 out of 4 times I start it up I won't have internet, I can unplug replug the ethernet port in and nothing does it to fix it, it's like the ethernet port doesn't work at all.

Once I restart the PC it always fixes the issue and it works as normal, this also happens wen I put the PC to sleep, on wake 1 out of 4 or 5 times I won't have internet and will have to restart the PC.

I two ethernet ports on the motherboard and have tried both and both have the same issue, I have updated the Bios to the latest drivers and still same issue. Anyone have any possible suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: In order for us to have any possible suggestions, it would be helpful to know what OS are you using. Have you run any diagnostic utilities for the motherboard? Is the PC clean of viruses and malware? Any error logs in the Event Viewer?

Comment: @CharlieRB Hi Charlie, I'm running windows 10, and I haven't run any diagnostic tools on the motherboard and yes the PC is clean of viruses and malware, I don't have any error logs. I'm pretty good knowledge of PCs but this is one thing I can't figure out. I'll try to get the model for the motherboard.

Comment: Any questions are not doubting your capabilities because we don't know what they are. Questions are for clarification and details so we don't make any assumptions. With that said, I have another question now that I know the OS. :)  Was this an issue before upgrading to Windows 10? Try removing the device from Device Manager and reboot. If that doesn't help, and considering this in an on-board NIC, you may want to consider getting another NIC to see if that resolves it.

Comment: The issue was happening with Windows 8 too, I'll try the device manager, and I kind of thought this was more an issue with the motherboard rather than software but I would think if the port was bad on the motherboard it just wouldn't work, and it does this with both ports on the board.